# New div doesn't apear after submit React

Tags: reactjs

I have form in react:

```js
let isSubmitted = false
const {
  register,
  errors,
  handleSubmit
} = useForm < FormInput > ()
const onSubmit = (data: FormInput) => {
  axios
    .post(endpoint, data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      isSubmitted = true
    })
    .catch(err => {})
}
```

```html
return (
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
        <Grid style={formGrid} container>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <div style={formItem}>
              <input style={inputStyle} placeholder="Name of Provider" name="provider" type="text" ref={register({ required: true })} />
              <div style={erroStyle}>{errors.Provider && 'Provider is required'}</div>
            </div>
            <div style={formItem}>
              <input placeholder="Name of Contact Person" name="contactPerson" ref={register({ required: true })} style={inputStyle} />
              <div style={erroStyle}>{errors.ContactPerson && 'Contact person is required'}</div>
            </div>
            <div style={formItem}>
              <input placeholder="Contact Email" name="email" ref={register({ required: true })} style={inputStyle} />
              <div style={erroStyle}>{errors.Email && 'Contact email is required'}</div>
            </div>
            <input onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} type="submit" style={submitStyle} />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <div style={formItem}>
              <input placeholder="Address (optional)" required name="address" style={inputStyle} ref={register} />
            </div>
          </Grid>
          {isSubmitted &&
          <div>Thank you! Form submitted, we'll contact you shortly.</div>}
        </Grid>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
) }
```

on submit I want to show this div: `{isSubmitted && <div>Thank you! Form submitted, we'll contact you shortly.</div>}` however it doesn't appear. I'm new to react and I'm looking from angular perspective and if it was angular it would work :) what I am missing here?

Comment: please define the isSubmitted as the state in the component.
For example, 
      const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false)
      after submitting the form, you can do that just like this.
      ...
         setIsSubmitted(true)
      ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React will only re-render your component if the state has changed, any update on a variable will not trigger a re-render.

Assuming you are using a function component, you have to use the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to allow your component to re-render:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// --- snip ---

const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

const {
  register,
  errors,
  handleSubmit
} = useForm < FormInput > ()
const onSubmit = (data: FormInput) => {
  axios
    .post(endpoint, data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      setIsSubmitted(true)
    })
    .catch(err => {})
}
```